# Ошибки на странице "Создавать синонимы меток"

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация, справка, привилегии

В описании привилегии ["Создавать синонимы меток"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) имеется следующий текст:

> Еще ниже будет окошко, где можно предложить другой синоним. синонима достигает 4 баллов, метка считается принятой и становится активной.

Должно быть что-то вроде:

> Когда рейтинг синонима достигает

Comment: "метка считается принятой и становится активной" — какая-то бессмысленная фраза, метки же не бывают неактивными. Это синоним считается принятым и становится активным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опубликовал статью для улучшения в [специальной теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5574/).