# Улучшение раздела справки о привилегиях «Создавать синонимы меток»

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка

Заголовок: create tag synonyms
Подзаголовок: Decide which tags have the same meaning as others

---

#### What are tag synonyms?

Tag synonyms allow us to fix incorrect tags by substituting them with the correct tags.

#### When should I propose a tag synonym?

Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged with the wrong or incorrect tag -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a good idea to propose a tag synonym. The goal is to avoid [manually editing the tags](/help/privileges/edit) on every post by making the retagging *automatic* for common tag mistakes.

#### How do I propose or vote on tag synonyms?

Users with this privilege and a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms.

When viewing a tag, look for the box at the top of the page which contains information about the tag with links below it. The last one in that list will be a link to the synonyms page. If there are already synonyms that exist for the tag, the number of synonyms will be shown there as well.

[image: Finding the synonyms link.]

This page will list out all existing synonyms for the tag. Any suggested synonyms for the tag will appear below that with up and down arrows so that eligible users can vote on whether it is valid or invalid. Below that, there is also a box to suggest an additional synonym for that tag.

#### How do synonyms get approved?

When a tag synonym reaches a vote score of **4**, it is accepted and becomes active. If a tag synonym reaches a vote score of **-2** it is deleted.

#### What happens when a question is asked using a synonym?

Any tags that match active synonyms will be automatically and silently changed from their original as-entered form to the tag that the synonym points to.

This also increments a synonym counter, which you can view at /tags/synonyms to evaluate the effectiveness (or ineffectiveness) of the synonyms that are in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовок: Создавать синонимы меток
Подзаголовок: Решайте, какие метки имеют схожее значение

---

#### Что такое синонимы меток?

Синонимы меток позволяют заменять неправильные метки на правильные.

#### Когда стоит предлагать синоним метки?

Если вы видите, что вопрос несколько раз помечают неправильной или не соответствующей меткой (или составной, что тоже не подходит), то хорошая идея - предложить синоним. Основной замысел в том, чтобы избежать постоянных [исправлений меток вручную](/help/privileges/edit) и добиться автоматических исправлений часто повторяемых ошибок.

#### Как предложить синоним метки или проголосовать за него?

**Предлагать** синоним метки могут пользователи с общим рейтингом ответов не менее 5 баллов и соответствующей привилегией. **Голосовать** за синоним могут пользователи с общим рейтингом меток (сумма всех «за» и «против») не менее 5 баллов.

Просматривая метки, найдите окошко в верхней части страницы, где содержится информация о метках со ссылками ниже. Последняя из них будет ссылкой на страницу синонимов. Если у данной метки есть синонимы, будет также указано их количество.

[image: Finding the synonyms link.]

На этой странице будут перечислены все синонимы данной метки. Предложенный синоним появится ниже, рядом с ним будут стрелки вверх и вниз, чтобы пользователи путем голосования могли решить, подходит ли новая метка. Еще ниже будет окошко, где можно предложить другой синоним.
синонима достигает **4** баллов, метка считается принятой и становится активной. В случае, если общий рейтинг синонима падает до **-2**, метка удаляется.

#### Что происходит, когда задают вопрос, отмеченный синонимом?

Все метки, соответствующие активным синонимам, автоматически изменятся по умолчанию с изначальных на новые.

Так же возрастут показатели счетчика синонимов (по ним можно оценить эффективность или неэффективность измененных меток), с которыми можно ознакомиться на /tags/synonyms.